# Preserving 'Model' between form posts and page requests in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, memory-management

To preserve model information between form posts and page requests, I define the model I use as 'static', so I don't loose my model's information.

Let's say, I have 3 steps of action. First step, I let user to select Excel file. Second step, I create a DataSet and attach to my model. Third step, I validate the user input and update my DbContext based on DataSet. All these steps require a form post. (At the end of actions, I dispose the DataSet to release resources but there is no way to be sure that user cancelled the operation, therefore the DataSet object will remain in the memory.)

So my question is, keeping my model as static this way, is efficient regarding to the memory allocation on the server? Or would you suggest a better option?

Comment: You can use Session to save the model.... tell me if you need an example

Comment: Preserving a static model through multiple requests results in every user having the same model. I'm sure that's not what you want.

Comment: @HenkMollema This operation requires an admin privilege and there will be one administrator for the whole site. So I didn't think about multiple access but you are correct. When it comes to 2 or more admins, 'static' will make a lot of troubles. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a bad idea. First of all if multiple users are using this static model at once then your model won't be consistent for each user. There are 3 places you typically put your state:

1. Write it to the form as hidden fields which you can post back again - this won't really work for your excel file but may be useful to persist the other state of your model.
2. Write to session state. For your excel file you might want to write to a file system and then store the filename in the session state.
3. Write to the db. You could put your excel file in the db, or put your excel file into the file system and store a path to the file in the db. Once the user gets past the 3rd step you could set a flag that this data is to be kept, or move it to another table. And you could periodically run a job which cleans up data where the user didn't get to the 3rd step.

Comment: I already use a Session object in the controller to keep ajax progress, therefore why not use Session? Good idea. Just, I have to create DataSet 2 times, which I wanted to avoid. Because in the 2nd step, I let user to select which table he/she will use and which columns are to be updated. In the 3rd step, I update the DbContext based on setup in the 2nd step. Anyway, creating DataSet 2 times is better than ridiculous usage of static. Thank you for your contribution.